# Сравнение двух дат в C#

Tags: c#, datetime

Мне нужно сравнить две даты(DateTime) и узнать является их разница больше X дней. Я понимаю что тут дело в логике, но я не могу сам написать эту функцию.

Что мне нужно:

- Функция, проверяющая больше одна дата относительно второй даты на X дней.

Пример кода:

```
DateTime DT1 = new DateTime(20, 9, 2020);   // 20.09.2020
DateTime DT2 = DateTime.Now;   // Сегодня 01.10.2020

if(Func(DT1, DT2, 30))
   Console.WriteLine("30 дней еще не прошло");
else
   Console.WriteLine("30 прошло");

// ...

static bool Func(DateTime DT1, DateTime2, int interval)   // Две сравниваемые даты, кол-во дней
{
   // Здесь я не смог описать логику
   // return true если разница двух дней меньше interval
}

// Вывод: 30 дней еще не прошло
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У структуры `DateTime` есть перегруженный оператор `-`, возвращающий [`TimeSpan`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=netcore-3.1):

```cs
public static TimeSpan operator -(DateTime a, DateTime b);
```

Таким образом вы можете получить интервал м-ду 2-мя датами:

```
if ((DT2 - DT1).Days > 30) // вместо `if (Func(DT1, DT2, 30))`
{ ... }
else
{ ... }
```

---

Возможно, вам понадобится перевести `TimeSpan` в дни. Для этого используется св-во `TotalDays` типа `double`, т.е. 2 дня 12 часов превратятся в 2,5 дня. Для обратного преобразования используется статический метод `FromDays(double days)`.